# Grant vs PassportJS vs OAuth2-client-js which one to use for mobile app login?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, node-modules

I need to write login with node js for mobile app, which includes simple login, FB, Twitter and Instagram logins. I was roaming on articles to decide between oAuth1 and oAuth2 and it seemed to me that the oAuth2 is more acceptable for mobile apps. However, node js has 3 libs for OAuth2, which are Grant, PassportJS and OAuth2-client-js. Which one I should pick between these 3 and why?

Answer (score 0):

The one which has more downloads (daily or last week).